# Is it possible to monitor an EventMachine process with NewRelic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, eventmachine, newrelic

I have an Eventmachine process that I start from my Procfile on Heroku.  I'm wondering if anyone has figured out to monitor this with NewRelic?

I'm interested in where to optimize database queries in it etc and just generally profile it.  I assume there is some way to get the stats for it in the 'background' section of NewRelics RPM in addition to the web request it is already profiling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try force-starting the New Relic Ruby agent. See "[Controlling when the Ruby agent starts](http://newrelic.com/docs/ruby/force-the-ruby-agent-to-start)".

Answer (score 1):

Newrelic does not yet support instrumentation of eventmachine at this time.  At best for EM based apps you can instrument your dispatcher and get high level statistics on the process.

Answer (score 0):

See "[NewRelic transaction traces in a Ruby Gem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17497360/459863)".

We use a timer to fire in regular intervals, e.g. every 500ms and measure the delay between the expected and the actual firing time. We pipe this output to a New Relic custom dashboard. That gives us some indication of the "health" of the EventMachine process.